# How to combine info from multiple variables into one in SPSS?

Tags: spss

I have problem with this basic task. I need to combine info from multiple variables into one. I know how to do it in R, but unfortunately I have to it in SPSS and it drives me crazy.

I know it is basic, but I would really appreciate if you could help me with this one.

My dataset looks like this:

```
Russian  German Chinese
Yes       No     No
Yes       No     No
No        Yes    No
n.v.t.    n.v.t  n.v.t.
No        No     Yes
```

That is how it should look like:
Russian = 1, German = 2, Chinese = 3.

```
Nationality
1
1
2
-
3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example is easily solved like this:

```
if Russian="Yes" Nationality=1.
if German="Yes" Nationality=2.
if Chinese="Yes" Nationality=3.
exe.
```

If the problem is more complex than that please edit your post and explain what other problems need to be solved, and I can add to the solution accordingly.